# Android custom XML view template

Tags: android, xml

I have a custom-styled checkbox that I'd like to replicate a number of times in my Android app. The XML for this checkbox is:

```
<CheckBox
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:button="@drawable/checkbox_large"
    android:text="Temporary Text"/>
```

Obviously, I can simply copy the XML and paste it lower down in my layout file, but in the event that I want to change the design I would have to do it for every pasted checkbox.

Is there a clean way to create a custom template for this checkbox, or should I be implementing this in code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a clean way to create a custom template for this checkbox, or should I be implementing this in code?

You can use [styles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html). Create

```
<style name="MyCheckbox">
     <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:button">@drawable/checkbox_large</item>
    <item name="android:text">Temporary Text</item>
</style>
```

and then just apply to all checkboxes you want:

```
<CheckBox 
    style="@style/MyCheckbox"/>
```

When in need of change, just alter your style.